# VBA Error Method '_Default' of Object 'Range' failed while adding 2nd data entry into Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a UserForm to track Job applications. Once user fills in the textboxes and click save, it transfers data from textboxes to excel sheet named "Database". The following code is my `Sub Save` which runs inside Save_CmdBt_Click event. When I enter my first data record and click save, everything works fine - no error. However, when I enter second data record, I get **Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed** error. While debugging, it fails at `.Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 5` line in code.

```vb
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
       
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")                'actual database sheet
    
    If UserFormV2.RowNumber_Textbox.Value = "" Then         'when I debug for 2nd record
        iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1                   'this line of code was executed, thus, txtbox value was "" for sure
    Else
        iRow = UserFormV2.RowNumber_Textbox.Value           'set to "" unless user selects one entry from listbox
    End If
    
    With sh
        '.Activate
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 5 '-5 because that is first available row after Table header. 
        ' The above code adds record number (1,2,3...) in excel table. 

        '.Cells(iRow, 3) = UserFormV2.CompanyName_TextBox1.Value ... my extra code
        
    End With
```

I have check the following post ([VBA Error Method of '_Default' if object 'range' failed when inserting into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243695/15685248)) but I do not have any textbox when the error triggers. Any idea or suggest how I can resolve this issue?

---

**Edit 2** - Added Images of Excel sheet and comparison between working and non-working sub save method.

---

**Edit 3** - Images removed. Error is in Listbox which gets updated after every save/delete calls.

---

### **Edit 4 (Solution to Problem)**

If and Else statement regarding the ListBox1 was the cause of the error. Essentially, I wanted to have a dynamic ListBox and initially had conditions that only applies to second row in the table (which is the header and first row). Thus, after **2nd record/data**, the ListBox would not update since it cannot due to set conditions thus resulting **Method '_default' of Object 'Range' failed' error**.

Comment: I tried testing your code and wasn't able to reproduce the error with the first entry starting in row 5, can you add some sample data from your `"Database"` sheet? I also recomend [this post about finding the last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row) as the `Counta` method can be unreliable (such as if there is a blank cell in your data).

Comment: I tried replacing the Counta with End(xlUp) method to find last used row and still got the same error. What is really interesting is that I have original version of this code (this is V2), and version 1 works perfectly without any errors. I compared both Sub Save (v1 verus v2) and both are identical. I'll add the sample data from "Database" later today.

Comment: What is the value of `iRow` when you get the error? (To find out, `Debug.Print "iRow =", iRow` just before the line that errors.  You'll see the value in the Immediate Window)

Comment: @chrisneilsen So I debug my code one section at time and my issue was with If Else statement for Listbox RowSource.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `iRow` is a valid number

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, iRow As Long
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database") 'actual database sheet
    
    If IsNumeric(RowNumber_TextBox.Value) Then iRow = RowNumber_TextBox.Value
    If iRow < 1 Then
       iRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Edit - IsNumeric added

Comment: Since `RowNumber_Textbox.Value` is set empty initially, this causes a problem since iRow is define as Long. Form can successful enter **FIRST** record/data from textboxes to excel without any errors. It throws error on second time when I click "Save" button.

Comment: @SpaceEngineer Yes, I forgot VB doesn't convert empty strings to 0 like some other languages - code updated. Interestingly I found while testing that  `[Counta(Database!A:A)]` returns 1 even when there is no sheet named Database. That surprised me.